# Stitching images without overlaps

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

I need to stitch images without overlaps.

The task will be more clear from the example:

Source:

[image]

Target:

[image]

Basicly I need a method that determines how well two images are joined to each other.

**UPDATE**

Using of random forest from OpenCv library allows to reach 80% of successful responses. Trained forest shows how well the two parts of puzzle fit each other.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you don't want the software to have a 5year old's encyclopdic knowledge of Disney characters - then your match is based on the point at which lines meet?

Just store a list of coords that a line hits the edge of a square and then compare each pair of squares minimising the difference in hit positions.

ps . Assuming the squares don't rotate just store a list of distance along each side for each side of the square.

Comment: Intersection for the lines with the boundaries of fragments - it's the first thing that came to mind. But this solution has several problems. First it often happens that the line is present on one fragment and not in the nearby. Secondly between fragments is the "invisible area" (red lines).
I thought of using machine learning. What do you think, if I can use CvRTrees::predict_prob from the OpenCV?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider dilate edges in each fragment, which could probably make up the losing edges in the read lines. Then, stitching fragments from this point.